# Custom Local Direct Route Windows

Tags: windows, routing, nat

I have an external IP address of a load balancer that I want to route locally for internal servers. What's the best way to do this?

I was thinking I could use the command line route command to add a local direct route to the internal IP address, but that doesn't seem to be working.

Ideas?

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: No error...it's just not resolving correctly as verified by pinging the external IP

Comment: Is this after you restart?

Comment: no, but I didn't think a restart was necessary to have routes take effect

Comment: Perhaps it's a firewall issue, then. If the route add command doesn't throw an error, then it may be an external issue such as a firewall.

Comment: good catch - that it was